# Как переобразовать строку в список для даты Python

Tags: python, split

Есть формат даты 16.05.2019 и нужно чтобы каждый элемент был в списке 
["16","05","2019"]

Answer (score 0):

```
date = "16.05.2019"
date = date.split(sep='.')
```